# Reuse a function type's argument definition

Tags: typescript

In typescript is there a way to reuse parameter types as follows:

```js
interface Box {
    create: (paramToReuse: (value: any) => void) => void
}
// is there a way to reference paramToResuse as a type? e.g.
let x: Box['create']['paramToReuse']
```

This can be done the other way around: by first defining paramToReuse and then referencing it in Box's interface, but can it be done the way I've shown above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's acceptable to reference it by its parameter index (`0`) instead of its name (`"paramToUse"`), that can be done with the helper type [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype), which takes a function and turns it into a tuple of its parameters:

```
interface Box {
    create: (paramToReuse: (value: any) => void) => void
}

let x: Parameters<Box["create"]>[0] // x is of type (value: any) => void
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeyDeBYAKGWOQSgjkgC5kAKABzijgFsAVdAJQgFcBnCDVoA3OABseg5HBABPAJTIAvAD5kw9MAAmi1es1bCAX0KExEMMkw0ACk1YXofADwZMAbQDkZCpE8BdFXcABn9kAHpwq2RgPmR0GGQwWXoUEXFJGhkFZTUNbSA)

Comment: Awesome - that works - thank you!